# Deserialize Json with same structure but different field names

Tags: java, json, gson

I have the following two Jsons

```
"attrs": {
        "rect": {
            "fill": "blue"
        },
        "text": {
            "fill": "white",
            "text": "my box"
        }
    }
```

and

```
"attrs": {
        "circle": {
            "fill": "red"
        },
        "text": {
            "text": "my circle",
            "fill": "yellow"
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to deserialize the JSON to the specific class namely `class Rect` and `class Circle` while parsing? I'm using Gson 2.4

This is how I call it right now:

```
Element[] element = gson.fromJson(arguments.toJson(), Element[].class);
```

And the Element class has this structure

```
public class Element {
    private Attributes attr;

public class Attributes{
        private Rectangle rect;
        private Circle circle;
    }
```

How can I tell gson to choose one of the fields? Right now one of them is going to be null and I dont want that since I will have way more shapes.

Comment: If I have understood the question, you can make two fields - `Rect rect` and `Circle circle`. Then, after parsing, one of them will be `null`, and the other one will have a value.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I put more code into my question.

Answer (score 0):

If "circle" or "rect" is always the first child, you can write simple `if else` logic to determine what class to use for deserialization.

Comment: This is not what I want to achieve. I edited my question